# Получение индекса элемента двумерного массива python

Tags: python, list

Есть двумерный массив:

```py
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Нужно получить индекс 1. Если бы это был обычный массив, то индекс элемента находиться так: l.index(1). Но как получить индекс 1 в двумерном массиве.

Comment: что значит _индекс 1 в двумерном массиве_? 6 или (1,2)?

Comment: Только написав нужную функцию самостоятельно. Она всего лишь обходит весь в массив в поиске нужного элемента, так что проблемы ее написание составить не должно

Answer (score 5):

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]])

print(np.where(l==1))
```

Вывод:

```py
(array([1], dtype=int64), array([2], dtype=int64))
```

`array([1], dtype=int64)` - индекс строки

`array([2], dtype=int64))` - индекс столбца

```py
>>> print(l[np.where(l==1)])
[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]

index = 0
index2 =0
for i in l:  
    try:
        index2 = i.index(1)
    except ValueError:
        index2 = -1
    if index2 != -1:
        break
    index += 1
print(index)
print(index2)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]

index = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist].index(1)
row, col = index//4, index % 4
print(index, row, col) # 6 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант:

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
 
ind = [ [i, _list.index(1)] for i,_list in enumerate(l) if 1 in l[i] ]

print(*ind)
```

Answer (score 3):

Все таки, если есть желание использовать `enumerate`, то вот так:

```py
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]]

# функция одного прохода, до первого совпадения
# если совпадения не случилось, возвращает None
def find_index_2D(l:list, value:int) -> dict:
    for row, sublist in enumerate(l):
        if (bool(set(sublist) & {value})): 
            return {"row":row, "column":sublist.index(value)}
```

Но если заглянуть в документацию по [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), то можно увидеть, что реализация и эквивалент достаточно просты:

```py
# эквивалент
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

то есть можно определить свое `n` без `enumerate` и увеличивать с каждым шагом `for`. То есть, вот так писать тоже нет ничего зазорного:

```py
def find_index_2D(l:list, value:int) -> dict:
    n = 0
    for sublist in l:
        if (bool(set(sublist) & {value})): 
            return {"row":n, "column":sublist.index(value)}
        n += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def getInd(list_in_list, value):
    for index_list, valuelist in enumerate(list_in_list):
         if value == valuelist[2]:
             return index_list
    else:
        print('Не нашел')
```

Или без привязки к индексу:

```
def getInd(list_in_list, value):
for index_list, valuelist in enumerate(list_in_list):
    for searchvalue in valuelist:
        if searchvalue == value:
            return index_list
else:
    return ('Не нашел')
```

Comment: Почему `2` в `valuelist[2]`? Как вы догадались проверять только этот элемент?

Comment: С тем же успехом можно было сразу вывести (1, 2) - типа и так видно, где единица написана)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Мне что то подсказывает, что тебе нужно будет вывести не только индекс, но и ряд, каком находится нужное число.

```
l = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
row = 1
for f in l:
    for num in f:
        if num == 1:
            print('index:', (f.index(1)))
            print('row:', row)
            break
    row += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

l = [[0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0]]
YX = np.where( l == 1 )
#(array([1], dtype=int32), array([2], dtype=int32))
Y = YX[ 0 ][0] #Y = 1
X = YX[ 1 ][0] #X = 2

    проверяем

print( l[ Y, X ] )
[1.]
print( l[ Y, X ][0] )
1.0
```

Дла двумерного массивв np.where( массив = число ) вернет кортеж ( Y, X ) поправил ответ добавил [0]  чтобы получить число а не массив 1X1

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]